# Resizing iframe to fit contents when the web page has a resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, resize, jquery-events

I have an iframe that hosts web pages from various websites. In the `onload` handler for the iframe I resize it to fit the contents using jQuery:

```
height = iframe.find('body').attr('scrollHeight') + 100
```

This works fine for most websites. However there is a website that has a `window.onresize` event which reloads the page. So it gets in an endless loop reloading the page where it is resized and therefore reloads the page.

How can I kill the resize event? I have tried all the following in my `onload` handler but none seem to work:

```
$('#webpage').resize(function() { alert("resizing"); return false});    
iframe.resize(function() { alert("resizing"); return false});    
window.onresize=null    
window.onresize=function() { alert("resizing"); return false};
```

Comment: What kind of silly site reloads itself on resize? :S

Comment: Heh@thirtydot -- I noticed chrome calls resize when you change tabs, I'm pretty sure I even caught it re-rendering the page?

Comment: @thirtydot: one written for Netscape 4, which memorably completely screwed up CSS when you resized the window. Reload-on-resize was a common workaround, although it was typically only done on a browser sniff such as `if (document.layers)`.

Comment: @simon: “from various websites”? You cannot read the height of pages from different sites than your own, full stop. It would be a cross-site-scripting vulnerability.

Comment: @bobince: Wow, I'm thankful I'm not old enough to have known that.

Comment: Oh yes, the Netscape era was a world of pain for everyone involved. These youngsters who complain about IE6 don't know how good they've got it! :-)

Comment: Simon-You are correct that they have to be from the same domain. I am reading the webpages from other sites on the server then serving the html from my own domain. Hence they appear to my browser as having originated in the same domain as the host page!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some crazy solution I simply don't know, the best way to stop the endless loop is probably to count how many times the `onload` handler for your `iframe` has been called. If it's been more than 1? 2? 3? times, then don't resize it.

Comment: Thanks. Did not like this very much but you prompted me to at least check if the height is different before changing it!